# System of integral equations describing probability

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, integral-equations

During my work on my thesis, I've stumbled upon the following problem:

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be some arbitrary PDFs with support $\mathbb{R}$. Does there exist a joint bivariate distribution $f_r(x, y)$, such that the marginal distribution of both $X, Y \sim f_r$ is $f_1$,and the distribution of $X+Y$ is $f_2$?

Writing this problem down as a system of integral equations, I've come up with this :

$$
\begin{cases} 
f_1(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_r(x, y) dy \\
f_1(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_r(x, y) dx \\
f_2(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_r(t, z-t) dt
\end{cases} $$

However, I don't have sufficient knowledge in solving PDEs to move this system anyway forwards.

If it is not solvable in general, I would be interested in the solution for some example distributions, e. g. normal or Cauchy. Numerical solution would also be sufficient. Please note that we cannot assume the independence of $X$ and $Y$, since then $f_r$ uniquely determines all marginals. If some additional requirements on $f_1,f_2$ need to be assumed, it's allowed.

EDIT: thanks to the comment of @geetha290krm, we must assume that $\mathbb{E}_{f_2} (X) = 2\mathbb{E}_{f_1} (X)$

Comment: Doesn't $E(X+Y)=EX+EY$ show that this is not possible in general?

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks, yes, this adds an additional requirement on $f_2$ given $f_1$. So we can restrict ourselves to cases where $\mathbb{E}_{f_2}(X) = 2 \mathbb{E}_{f_1}(X)$

Comment: ((1)) You should try with Specific ( & Easy ) $f_1$ & $f_2$ Cases to get a grasp on general Scenarios. ((2)) You can try converting Integral Equations to Equivalent (Partial) Differential Equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that even the assumption of $f_2$ having twice the mean of $f_1$ is far from sufficient. One can keep playing the game of matching moments: Assume for simplicity $f_1,f_2$ have mean $0$. Then since $$\text{Var}(X+Y)=\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)+2\text{Cov}(X,Y)$$ we get the additional relation $$\int x^2 f_2(x)dx=2\int x^2 f_1(x)dx+2\int\int xyf_r(x,y)dxdy.$$ This relation does not necessarily hold under the given assumption. You can add this as an additional assumption, though repeating this argument with higher moments gives more and more technical extra conditions on $f_r$ in relation to $f_1,f_2$.

However, we may look at a few special cases: Suppose $f_1=\phi_{\mu_1,\sigma_1}$ and $f_2=\phi_{\mu_2,\sigma_2}$ are Gaussians. Then assume that $\mu_2=2\mu_1$. By the Ansatz $$f_r=\phi\bigg(\begin{pmatrix}m_1 \\ m_2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}v_1 & \kappa  \\ \kappa & v_2\end{pmatrix}\bigg)$$ we get since $f_r$ must have both marginals being $f_1$:  $$m_1=m_2=\mu_1, \hspace{1cm} v_1=v_2=\sigma_1^2.$$ Now we see the problem I detailed above: If the variance $\sigma_1^2$ is small, then the variance of the sum cannot be too large. More precisely, let $X,Y$ have law $f_1$ and $X+Y$ have law $f_r$. Then we would necessarily have $$\sigma_2^2=2\sigma_1^2+2\kappa.$$ Altogether this would yield $$\kappa=\frac{\sigma_2^2-2\sigma_1^2}{2}.$$ However, since by the Cauch-Schwarz inequality we have for any random variables $X,Y$ that $$\bigg|\frac{\sigma_2^2-2\sigma_1^2}{2}\bigg|=|\kappa|=|\text{Cov}(X,Y)|\leq \sqrt{\text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)}=\sigma_1^2,$$ we see that this choice of $\kappa$ cannot always be valid. However, if this inequality holds, then we are able to construct a joint Gaussian law $f_r$ with the desired properties, as detailed above.

(*Note that in this case it was sufficient to enforce a condition on the second moments, since a Gaussian is uniquely determined by it's first two moments. In general, this is not the case, hence a condition on only the first two moments is not enough to allow such a construction of $f_r$*)

I believe that one may be able to get similar characterizations for general [*infinitely divisible distributions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability)). I will edit my answer to include such attempts when I can find the time :)

### EDIT:

I have thought about the problem some more and I have found that a very similar approach works for Cauchy distributions: Let $f_1,f_2$ be Cauchy, meaning $$f_1(x)=\frac{1}{\pi\gamma_1\big(1+\gamma_1^{-2}(x-x_0^{(1)})^2)},\hspace{0.5cm}f_2(x)=\frac{1}{\pi\gamma_2\big(1+\gamma_2^{-2}(x-x_0^{(2)})^2)}$$ with associated characteristic functions $$\phi_1(\theta)=\exp(i\theta x_0^{(1)}-|\theta|\gamma_1), \hspace{1cm}\phi_2(\theta)=\exp(i\theta x_0^{(2)}-|\theta|\gamma_2).$$ **Ansatz:** Assume that $f_r$ is multivariate Cauchy (see [here](https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/199588/Technical%20Report%20567%20Properties%20of%20Multivariate%20Cauchy%20and%20Poly-Cauchy%20Distributions%20with%20Bayesian%20g-Prior%20Applications.pdf?sequence=1) for a short introduction), meaning its characteristic function reads $$\phi(\theta)=\phi((\theta_1,\theta_2))=\exp\bigg(i\theta^T\mu - \big(\theta^T V\theta\big)^{1/2}\bigg)$$
The necessary condition $\phi((\theta,0))=\phi((0,\theta))=\phi_1(\theta)$ immediately implies $\mu_1=\mu_2=x_0^{(1)}$ as well as $$V_{1,1}=\gamma_1^2, \hspace{1cm} V_{2,2}=\gamma_1^2.$$
Furthermore, the condition $\phi((\theta,\theta))=\phi_2(\theta)$ implies $2x_0^{(1)}=x_0^{(2)}$ as well as (assuming $V$ is symmetric) $$2\gamma_1^2+2V_{1,2}=\gamma_2^2$$
which yields the choice $$V_{1,2}=V_{2,1}=\frac{\gamma_2^2-2\gamma_1^2}{2}.$$
Again, we need that $V$ is positve definite, hence there is some inequality constraint ensuring this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input! I wonder whether the constraints on $f_1$ and $f_2$ could be better modelled via characteristic functions? Keeping the lower index notation, I believe that the question may be restated as follows: find a positive definite function $\varphi_r$, s.t. $\varphi_r(t, 0) = \varphi_r(0, t) = \varphi_1 (t)$ and $\varphi_r(t, t) = \varphi_2(t)$. This could help us deal with all of the moments.

Comment: @NikoWielopolski That's an interesting approach, though to me it seems that this also is only useful in special cases. I have added the Cauchy distribution as an example in my answer, using this approach. However, my point remains: You need a lot more constraints than just $f_2$ having twice the mean of $f_1$ (at least assuming higher moments of $f_1,f_2$ exist), therefore one cannot expect a general solution to this problem, not even a guarantee for the existence of $f_r$. Since you asked about the Normal and Cauchy distributions, I hope my answer is now sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. I want to keep the bounty open for now, in case someone comes up with a more general solution for finding $f_r$. In the other case I'll award it to you

Answer (score 0):

It would be more reasonable to consider first the following problem: let $(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$, $(b_0,\ldots,b_m)$, $(c_0,\ldots,c_{n+m})$ be three probabilities. Does there exist a probability $(p_{ij})$ such that
$$\sum_ip_{ij}=b_j,\ \sum_jp_{ij}=a_i\sum_{i+j=k}p_{ij}=c_k?$$ The set of solutions $p$ is a convex set and it is easy to describe its extreme points, but the real difficulty is to decide when it is not empty.